# Error while trying to append Year in the XLSX sheet using glue function in R Programming

Tags: r, openxlsx, r-glue

Using R trying to print a sheet in xls output format.
Trying to get the year name in dynamically using a parameter in R.
Using this parameter trying to rename the Excel sheet year.
But glue string is printing instead of parameter.

```
if (!require("librarian"))install.packages("librarian")
librarian::shelf(stringr,stringi,dplyr,glue,openxlsx)
         

Year <-2021
Output_Path <-"C:\\Z_R_Stuff\\"
Excel_Output_List <- list('glue({Year}) MTCARS are Great'=mtcars,'IRIS'=iris)
File_Name <- "Test_Output_Excel"           

write.xlsx(Excel_Output_List, paste0(Output_Path,File_Name,".xlsx"))
```

```
    Output Issue
    Error Output:
    Sheet Name : glue({Year}) MTCARS are Great          
    Expected Output:
    Sheet Name : 2021 MTCARS are Great
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for that, try this:

```
Year <-2021
Output_Path <-"C:\\Z_R_Stuff\\"
Excel_Output_List <- list(mtcars,iris)
names(Excel_Output_List) <- c(glue('{Year} MTCARS are Great'), 'IRIS')
File_Name <- "Test_Output_Excel"

write.xlsx(Excel_Output_List, paste0(Output_Path,File_Name,".xlsx"))
```

Comment: You are welcome. I am really sorry for that it did not work the first time because I did not run the code. In this community I should be responsible for my put. But luckily, I corrected my mistake and it helped you. Thank you too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Excel_Output_List <- list(glue('{Year} MTCARS are Great')=mtcars,'IRIS'=iris)
```

Comment: The above code is not working, still getting the same output ,sheet name as glue({Year}) MTCARS are Great